# How to calculate average row-wise?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to think of how to average the values of many columns and put it into one column. However if there is a null value I would like to leave it out of the average calculation. To be more specific the table looks like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|           user|       month_01|       month_02|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       garrison|            3.2|            3.0|
|          marta|           null|            1.8|
|        garrett|            4.3|            7.8|
|         harold|            4.5|            3.1|
|          marta|            6.7|            7.2|
|           niko|            4.1|            5.8|
|          james|            9.5|           null|
|          manny|            1.9|            9.8|
|        charles|            7.8|            7.6| ...
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I would like to average all the months together to get a final table with two columns one with the user and one with the average of all the month values. However I do not want null values to play a factor so if there is one null value in all the months for a user row then you would just divide by 11. I am struggling to think about how to do this with Spark. The final table will look something like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|           user|        average|
+---------------+---------------+
|       garrison|           34.9|
|          marta|            2.3|
|        garrett|           4.43|
|         harold|            8.5|
|          marta|            6.0|
|           niko|            1.1|
|          james|            3.2|
|          manny|            0.7|
|        charles|            7.1|
+---------------+---------------+
```

So the average column is the average of all the values in the row for each user.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm using Scala as the programming language contrary to what was requested, i.e. Java)

### Solution 1 - map Operator

One solution that springs to my mind is to use [map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) operator.

> **map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]** Returns a new Dataset that contains the result of applying func to each element.

And so the solution would then be as follows:

```
scala> months.show
+--------+--------+--------+
|    user|month_01|month_02|
+--------+--------+--------+
|garrison|     3.2|     3.0|
|   marta|    null|     1.8|
| garrett|     4.3|     7.8|
|  harold|     4.5|     3.1|
|   marta|     6.7|     7.2|
|    niko|     4.1|     5.8|
|   james|     9.5|    null|
|   manny|     1.9|     9.8|
| charles|     7.8|     7.6|
+--------+--------+--------+

val solution = months.map { r =>
  val skipUserColumn = 1
  // be generic as much as possible
  // the number of months can be any number
  val monthsCount = r.size - skipUserColumn
  val nullCount = (skipUserColumn until r.size).count(r.isNullAt)
  val sum = (skipUserColumn until r.size).
    foldLeft(0.0) { 
      case (sum, idx) if !r.isNullAt(idx) => sum + r.getDouble(idx)
      case (sum, idx) => sum
    }
  (r.getString(0), sum / (monthsCount - nullCount))
}.toDF("user", "month_avg")
scala> solution.show
+--------+------------------+
|    user|         month_avg|
+--------+------------------+
|garrison|               3.1|
|   marta|               1.8|
| garrett|              6.05|
|  harold|               3.8|
|   marta|              6.95|
|    niko| 4.949999999999999|
|   james|               9.5|
|   manny|5.8500000000000005|
| charles| 7.699999999999999|
+--------+------------------+
```

### Solution 2 - withColumn Operator with functions

I *think* that using `map` operator is as much ineffective as the UDF-based one. They both are loading binary rows on JVM and so the memory requirement are higher than a solution that would avoid the copying (from the internal binary row format to a JVM object).

I *think* that the execution cost of `withColumn` operator with `functions` object could give a better performance (and be easier to understand).

```
val partial_solution = months.
  withColumn("months", array(months.columns.drop(1).map(col): _*)).
  withColumn("exploded", explode($"months"))
scala> partial_solution.show
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    user|month_01|month_02|     months|exploded|
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+
|garrison|     3.2|     3.0| [3.2, 3.0]|     3.2|
|garrison|     3.2|     3.0| [3.2, 3.0]|     3.0|
|   marta|    null|     1.8|[null, 1.8]|    null|
|   marta|    null|     1.8|[null, 1.8]|     1.8|
| garrett|     4.3|     7.8| [4.3, 7.8]|     4.3|
| garrett|     4.3|     7.8| [4.3, 7.8]|     7.8|
|  harold|     4.5|     3.1| [4.5, 3.1]|     4.5|
|  harold|     4.5|     3.1| [4.5, 3.1]|     3.1|
|   marta|     6.7|     7.2| [6.7, 7.2]|     6.7|
|   marta|     6.7|     7.2| [6.7, 7.2]|     7.2|
|    niko|     4.1|     5.8| [4.1, 5.8]|     4.1|
|    niko|     4.1|     5.8| [4.1, 5.8]|     5.8|
|   james|     9.5|    null|[9.5, null]|     9.5|
|   james|     9.5|    null|[9.5, null]|    null|
|   manny|     1.9|     9.8| [1.9, 9.8]|     1.9|
|   manny|     1.9|     9.8| [1.9, 9.8]|     9.8|
| charles|     7.8|     7.6| [7.8, 7.6]|     7.8|
| charles|     7.8|     7.6| [7.8, 7.6]|     7.6|
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

There's however one issue with the dataset which is that `user` column is not unique so it's impossible to use aggregation.

If the other `marta` from row 5 be excluded, I'd propose the following solution with my beloved window aggregates.

```
// Remember user column is now assumed unique
// I'm however not excluding it from calculation
// just assume that (user, month_01) would be unique
// user and all months together could get us closer to the requirement
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val userAndMonth01 = Window.partitionBy("user", "month_01")
val solution = partial_solution.
  withColumn("avg", avg("exploded") over userAndMonth01).
  select("user", "avg").
  distinct  // <-- be careful since we might get non-unique pairs of user and avg
scala> solution.show
+--------+------------------+
|    user|               avg|
+--------+------------------+
|  harold|               3.8|
|garrison|               3.1|
| garrett|              6.05|
|   manny|5.8500000000000005|
| charles| 7.699999999999999|
|    niko| 4.949999999999999|
|   marta|              6.95|
|   james|               9.5|
|   marta|               1.8|
+--------+------------------+
```